# Shell command - delay stdout log as path does not exist at command execution

Tags: python, bash, shell, logging, stdout

I have the following terminal command

`python run.py args > path/to/log.txt`

However, at execution, path/to/ does not exist as it is created on the fly by the python script, and which depends on quite complex `args`. Therefore, the log does not appear anywhere.

Is there a way to delay the log writing (by 5 seconds let's say), so that the python command have time to create `path/to/` ?

Comment: I know but this is not really an option as I try to keep the python script 'log'-less

Comment: You need your own logger

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write to somewhere in maybe `/tmp/` and move the log where you want it once it's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terrible idea.  But, if you must do it, you could do:

```
python run.py args |  { sleep 1; cat > path/to/log.txt; }
```

However, since you must know the `path/to` prior to invoking this, you might as well just do: `mkdir -p path/to; python run.py args > path/to/log.txt` . It's not writes to the log that you are trying to delay, but opening/creation of the file.  When you run `cmd > p/a/t/h`, the shell will attempt to open `p/a/t/h` before it invokes `cmd`.  If it cannot open `p/a/t/h,`cmd` will never be invoked.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it a terrible idea? There is a command in python that creates the path based on some arguments in args but also other variables. Using it prior to the `run.py` to get the `path/to` is an option but has the drawback of increasing the complexity of my bash command - which was intended to be easy to use : run a command and log the stdout.

Comment: Any hackery you do to try to delay the opening of the log file will be far more complex than the simple solution of creating the directory first.  You can always factor out the name and do: `f=path/to/; mkdir -p "$f"; python run.py args > "$f"/log.txt;`

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box a little, assuming you *have* to have this log where you want it before the script ends...

```
set -x                                    # log *this* process
tmp=$(mktemp)                             # make a throwaway filename
python run.py args 2>$tmp 1>&2 &          # log in bg to $tmp
until [[ -d path/to/ ]]; do sleep 1; done # wait for dir to exist
ln $tmp path/to/log.txt &&                # hard link log where you need it
  rm $tmp                                 # clean the temp if successful
```

This assumes `path/to/` is on the same device as `/tmp/`. If not, you'll need to create a temp location that *is* on the same device, because the whole point of this exercise is that it's a ***hard*** link, not a symlink. Once the link is created you can remove the first path and it will be as if you wrote to the second path location all along. The data will still be in the same file at the same disk location and inode number, just referenced by a new name through the desired path.

c.f. [this guide](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-ln-command-examples/), especially #10 at the bottom.

Note that I captured stderr to the log, too. You'll want that most of the time, in the same log or to one of it's own. Note that I actually redirected stderr to the log, and then dup'd stdout to stderr - this may cost you the efficiency of buffering, but can save you the headache of miscollated lines caused by separately buffered streams written to the same output.

Comment: Nice.  I think the final sentence shows that we need a better terminology for discussing objects in the file system.  Rather than "same disk location and inode nuber", it's accurate to say "same file".  We (as a culture) need to stop conflating paths and files.  A path is a string containing a leading directory and an entry in that directory.  The entry in the directory is a link to a file.  We need a better word for the entry in the directory, and we need to stop using the word "file" for that entity.

Comment: I actually meant the terms the way you use them, but I phrase things oddly for some folk, lol. Being overly specific, perhaps. ;) Edited anyway.

Comment: I think your specificity is good.  I'm just searching for a word to use to replace the last few decades of incorrect usage of the word "file".  We shouldn't call entries in a directory "files".  Perhaps we should call them "links".  If that became common usage, people would be less mystified by the concept of a link.

Comment: I have always just referred to them as "directory entries". The file is usually what we are talking about, so we gloss over the fact that how you find it is important, lol